# Visualizing magnetic moments of Quantum espresso input/output files

Tags: quantum-espresso, atomic-simulation-environment, visualization-software, magnetism

I am looking for a software/website that can visualize atomic structure of my quantum espresso input/output files with magnetic moments. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I want to add a temporary solution using VESTA. It involves the following steps:

1. I import my quantum espresso input file using xcrysden, then I export it as a *.xsf file.
2. I use vesta to read the *.xsf file and then save it as a *.cif file. This is because I knew that vesta can plot *.mcif file which has magnetic information in it.
3. I observe a sample *.mcif file (say [this](https://www.cryst.ehu.eus/magndata/index.php?index=1.580)), and notice that It ends with something like:

   loop_
   _atom_site_moment.label
   _atom_site_moment.crystalaxis_x
   _atom_site_moment.crystalaxis_y
   _atom_site_moment.crystalaxis_z
   _atom_site_moment.symmform
   _atom_site_moment.magnitude
   Fe 2.220517  0.000031 0.00000 mx,my,mz
   .
   .
   .

   I make these modifications in my cif file and change the extension.
4. Open my mcif file using VESTA.

It is a bit cumbersome but does the job.